# Specify a "back-up" load path with Load-Time Dynamic Linking?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

When using 'Load-Time Dynamic Linking'(using an import library .lib in compilation that loads a dll when the module is loaded) in a Win32 application, is it possible to affect the search order?

The goal is to have a library loaded using the normal search order, with a back-up path if one is not found on the normal path.

Example: foo.lib is linked in the project.  At load time:

1. If foo.dll is present in the System path or any of the other paths mentioned in [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) then it will be loaded.
2. Else mySpecifiedPath/foo.dll will be loaded.

Clarification:  The back-up dll should only be loaded if no version of the dll is found in the standard LoadLibrary search paths.

Comment: You can enable delay-loading, and set up the DLL search directories early during application startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving the old answer at the bottom and adding a new one at the top:

The combination of delay-loading and the delay-load [Failure Hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfcfb0a3.aspx) as described at  provides a nice way to handle this.

Register the failure hook that loads the back-up dll before using any symbol from the library.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include <delayimp.h>

//access to set the failure hook
ExternC PfnDliHook   __pfnDliFailureHook2;

const char* dllName = "foo.dll";
const char* dllBackupPath = "pathToBackup\\foo.dll";
FARPROC WINAPI DelayLoadHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{
    //if the failure was failure to load the designated dll
    if (dliNotify == dliFailLoadLib &&
        strcmp(dllName, pdli->szDll) == 0 &&
        pdli->dwLastError == ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        printf("loading back-up dll\n");
        //return the successfully loaded back-up lib,
        //or 0, the LoadLibrary fails here
        HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryA(dllBackupPath);
        return (FARPROC)lib;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //set the Failure Hook
    __pfnDliFailureHook2 = &DelayLoadHook;

    //when this function is called the library will be loaded
    //from standard paths.  If it is not found the Failure Hook
    //set above will be called.
    int test = ::intReturningFuncFromFooDll();
    printf("%d", test);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

===========old answer below==============

Looks like what I was looking for is delay-loading, as mentioned in the comment by IInspectable.  I found information regarding this:

[Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx)

Here is some code demonstrating the usage I mentioned in the original post:

```
  //load the dll using the normal search
  HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary( L"foo.dll" );
  //if unsuccessful, try a specified path
  if (lib == NULL)
  {
    LoadLibrary( L"mySpecifiedPath/foo.dll" );
  }
  if (lib == NULL)
  {
    //make sure that the library is not used, 
    //or exit the application, as it was not found
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

edit to old answer: This dynamic loading would be used before any symbol from the library is used.  The delay loaded fills out the symbol addresses using the module loaded here the first time a symbol from the library is accessed.

Comment: The code demonstrates runtime-dynamic linking. While it can accomplish the same result, it is a lot of work. Delay-loading delays import resolution from load time to first use, giving you a window of opportunity to set the DLL search path, by calling [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx), for example. No need for explicit `LoadLinrary` and `GetProcAddress` calls.

Comment: On older OS versions that do not support `AddDllDirectory()`, you can use `SetDllDirectory()` instead. On even older OS versions that do not support that, you can use a [delay-load `failure hook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfcfb0a3.aspx) to load the backup file.

Comment: @IInspectable I should have expanded the answer.  I am not ever calling GetProcAddress.  I am loading the library in advance of first access and letting the delay loader fill out my procedure addresses on first call.  This allows me to detect the absence of normal search path AND my back-up dll at the beginning of my program and report the total failure early.  I did see the AddDllDirectory as well, but I could not find anything in the documentation that guaranteed my library would be the last one checked, as I require.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I could not find anything indicating that I could guarantee my back-up library would be checked last if I used AddDllDirectory() or SetDllDirectory() so I did not consider those options.  Now that I've seen the delay-load failure hook, that seems like the way to go.  I can simply set the hook, then call some function from the library early in my program, checking that both the library exists and all the function addresses loaded correctly, and handle either type of failure as I see fit.

Comment: @NicholasSpencer: in a failure hook, all you have to do is check if `dliNotify` is `dliFailLoadLib`, `pdli->szDll` is `foo.dll`, and `pdli->dwLastError` is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.  If so, then have the hook call `LoadLibrary()` to load your backup file and return the loaded `HMODULE`. Don't do anything about missing function addresses, as presumably the backup file exports all of the functions your app needs. You should only handle the case of missing functions if you know the DLL might not export some functions and you want to provide your own replacement functions for them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with the statement on handling the case where `dliNotify` is `dliFailLoadLib`, but in the case where `dliNotify` is `dliFailGetProc` I might as well note in my log the fact I failed to load expected symbols and possibly notify the user of an issue and exit my program.  Else I may come across perplexing access violations due to calling procaddresses that are set to NULL, when they could be easily found in my log.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) documentation, it should be obvious, that the final location searched is the `PATH` environment variable. Applying that knowledge, the easiest solution that meets all your requirements is to append the backup location to the `PATH` variable.

This could be done in two ways:

1. An external launcher: The [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) API call allows an application, to pass a custom environment to the new process through the *lpEnvironment* argument. The current process' environment block can be queried by calling [GetEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx).
2. Enable delay-loading of the desired DLL(s) using the [/DELAYLOAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) linker option, and modify the process' environment at application startup. After retrieving the `PATH` environment variable (using [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188.aspx)), it can be modified and updated in the environment block by calling [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx).

Comment: The reason I did not consider modifying `PATH` is because I could not find any guarantee in the documentation on the order that the directories in `PATH` would be searched.  While I fully expect the first one added and therefore any that the user has in the global `PATH` on the PC to be checked first, I prefer not to rely on undefined behavior.